# How to read a REG Value into an Environment Variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I am trying to read a REG Value into an Environment Variable in a BAT file.  E.g.,

REG HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog /v ImagePath

I can get the entire output string of the REG command into an environment variable like this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%a in (`REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog" /v ImagePath`) DO set ImagePath=%%a
```

However, this sets the environment variable to the entire line, i.e.,

```
ImagePath   REG_EXPAND_SZ   C:\Windows\system32\services.exe
```

I want the Environment Variable to consist only of the path portion, i.e.,

```
C:\Windows\system32\services.exe
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog" /v ImagePath') DO set ImagePath=%%B
```

The default delimiter is space and tab; no need to change it. TOKENS=2* stores the 2nd token in %%A and the remainder of the line in %%B.

Concerning your original code - there is no benefit to using USEBACKQ in your situation. Also, your code would not preserve the entire line if it contained `=` because you used that as the delimiter.

***Answer to comment***
If you can rely on the fact that the path does not contain any spaces, then you can simply use "TOKENS=3" and save %%A. But I wouldn't trust that. Instead, I would use

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog" /v ImagePath') DO (
  for %%F in (%%B) do (
    set ImagePath=%%F
    goto :break
  )
)
:break
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Just realized I have to take it one step further. Lets say the ImagePath is this: 

"C:\Windows\system32\services.exe" parameter