# Batch file:Setting a registry value to a variable

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, registrykey

You think it would easy to google how to set a reg value to a variable in a batch file, but it is consistently different as does not work for my purposes. PowerShell/VBS are out of the question currently and I believe this is possible using a .bat file.

When I use this command:

```
REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windowsupdate /v WUServer
```

Output:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windowsupdate
   WUServer    REG_SZ    http://AAA-WUS-MHQ1234
```

I just want:

```
http://AAA-WUS-MHQ1234
```

and stored as a variable so I can go echo %WSUSServer%

I've tried set and it just sets the command not the output, as well I can't seem to get token, delim, or array to work, but perhaps I am misunderstanding how they work.

Please teach how to use set to make the server a variable.

Many thanks!

Update:
So I have tried this, but just in the cmd line and I get %%L not expected...I entered it as one word, does it have to be in a batch file with indents? I wouldn't think so, but am trying now:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,* skip=2" %%L IN ( reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKTools" /v InstallationFolder ) DO SET sdkpath=%%M
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a REG Value into an Environment Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359001/how-to-read-a-reg-value-into-an-environment-variable) and [Reading a registry value to a batch variable, handling spaces in value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22352793)

Comment: I've tried that code, but I can't seem to get it to work (mind you I am trying just in the cmd prompt, but I get "%%L not expected" and that is using the code below in one line

Comment: FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,* skip=2" %%L IN (
    `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKTools" /v InstallationFolder`
) DO SET sdkpath=%%M

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried, and add the information about how it doesn't work as you'd expect there instead of burying it in the comment clutter? Information relevant to your question belongs in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do what you've actually said, and use the backqtokens (`` ` ``). (Also, from the command line you only need one `%`; in a batch file, you'd use two (`%%`.)

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,* skip=2" %%L IN (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKTools" /v InstallationFolder`) DO SET sdkpath=%%M
```